# ppapi_error_code_10870 - Please go to the App Store to install the latest version of the PayPal app

Tags: ios, paypal, sandbox

I've been successfully testing my app with the PayPal iOS SDK for the past few days and for some reason today it now presents me with the message below when I try to launch the View Controller.

**"ppapi_error_code_10870 - Please go to the App Store to install the latest version of the PayPal app."**

I'm using the latest SDK version (1.1.1) and can set it to production mode and get the View Controller to load just fine.

Comment: You are testing against sandbox, correct? (Not live/production?)

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the environment to sandbox mode before I call prepareForPaymenUsingClientId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@James Parker, Dave from PayPal here.

I think that you and we are discussing this issue in three places now![*] How about we consolidate the discussion to just one? My suggestion would be https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/31

Thanks!

-- Dave

[*] [New PayPal iOS SDK(1.0.5) - Can't connect to sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526430/new-paypal-ios-sdk1-0-5-cant-connect-to-sandbox/17666044?noredirect=1#comment27113573_17666044)

[ppapi_error_code_10870 - Please go to the App Store to install the latest version of the PayPal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451926/ppapi-error-code-10870-please-go-to-the-app-store-to-install-the-latest-versio)

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/31